# Musicplayer with onebutton

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am new to android. I'm trying to create a music player which will play specific MP3 with one button(play/pause).I want button's background change between two image when click

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....
**mp** is mediaplayer object
use your image at `btn_play and btn_pause`

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Concise and to the point. However, it might be beneficial to show OP quickly how to set which MP3 file is assigned to the MediaPlayer.